# How can i install back windows 7 after install linux if i lost my windows 7 product key?

Tags: linux, windows-7, installation, centos-7, product-key

I bought my pc together with the windows 7. After a while, i decided to use linux. So, i install centos 7 on that pc. Now, there is a software which i only know can run in windows 7. So, i have to install back windows 7. However, i lost product key. I only have the product id. Can anyone help me to install windows 7?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/367011/boot-windows-7-iso-from-grub2 might be a useful starting point, but the answer seem... somewhat speculative. Getting a 4gb or so thumbdrive seems the sane option here.

Comment: side question - do you already have a partition for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost all copies of the product key, you’re out of luck. You will have to acquire a new license.

However, copies of the product key or a digital entitlement may remain in the following locations:

- Old full system backups
- E-Mails or the case in which the Windows DVD came
- If you ever upgraded to Windows 10 while it was free, Microsoft